# Save and open multi line edit-text data in android

Tags: android

I am new to android and java. The logic for my app is working fine but i want to save the data entered by the user in a text file(multiple files under different names) and i want the user to decide that name when clicked the SAVE button and when clicked OPEN button i want to open the folder in which all the text files were saved in order to select a file the user wants to display or edit in edit-text.[used this link but did not get what i wanted](http://codetheory.in/android-saving-files-on-internal-and-external-storage/)

Comment: `i want to save the data entered by the user in a text file(multiple files under different names)` A database would be more efficient.

Comment: so what is your specific problem?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. List all files from desired folder -

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Folder";

   File dir= new File (path);

   File [] files = dir.listFiles();
   String names = new String[files.length];
   for(int i=0; i<files.length;i++)
   {
     names[i]=files[i].getName();

   }
   ```

Now you have array names, so you can display it in a ListView
if not than refer to this link : http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90

2. Open files on click on List Item.

Start another activity on ListItem and used `intent.putStringExtra("path","youPath");`
to get the desired file path there.

Than open that file and set its text to an `EditText` or `TextView`.

3. Give user option to Rename -

You can set `OnItemLongClickListener` for this, so `onLongClick()` you can show a dialog to show the file name with `EditText`.

I`d suggest to learn Java File class and Android basics (ListView,EditText,TextView and Intents), before doing this, otherwise you will get confused easily.